# Android: Can't Pass Data Read From File To Multiple Classes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, onclicklistener

I am having trouble passing data read from a text file to another class in the app.  I can read from the file just fine, but I think I need to use Bundle, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I would like to have the second class handle the data from the text file, and then display it in the first class.

*Edit: I've figured out how to pass the string from the file using an intent.  I'm still working on getting some of the bugs out.*

*2nd Edit: I know there is a more efficient way of doing this.  The only way I can get it to work is to have the first button in MainActivity use startActivity(intent) to allow secondActivity to bundle the string read from the file.*

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    Button bReadFile;
    TextView tvRead;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        bReadFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        tvRead = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //trying to find a way to remove this button
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, econdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        bReadFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
                tvRead.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

secondActivity.java:

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent mIntent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("key", readDataFile());
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }

    public String readDataFile() {
        String strData = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data_text);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            strData = br.readLine();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange what you are doing. from mainactivity you are calling secondactivity and in second you are again starting mainactivty in oncreate() then what is the use this secondactivity. you can have that readDataFile() method in mainactivity itself.
Is it that you are trying to do something what is your actual requirement

Comment: What I really want to do is have the secondActivity handle reading the text file.  I had it set up as you suggested with MainActivity handling the file input, but I wanted to move it to another class as I added more content.

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining very well.  I want the second class to handle the contents of the file, and then send the contents to the first class as needed.  I've updated the code to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below edited code for your requirement
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    Button bReadFile;
    TextView tvRead;
    String value;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        bReadFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        tvRead = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMain);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //trying to find a way to remove this button
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResults(intent,0);
            }
        });

        bReadFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tvRead.setText(value);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       value = data.getStringExtra("key");
}
}
```

the code for secondActivity.java

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("key", readDataFile());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
    }

    public String readDataFile() {
        String strData = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data_text);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            strData = br.readLine();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.  It looks like the setResult method was what I was looking for.